# Can you supply an object to a function later in Scala?

Tags: scala

I see something like this in Scala and I'm wondering what this concept is even called.

```
def function1(f: Dog => String): String = {
...
var doggy = new Doggy("fido")
Await.result(f(doggy)
}

function1(_.functionDefinedInDog)
```

What is this concept?

Comment: If the compiler can't compile it, then it is referred to as "broken."

Comment: @Jwan622 Which part?

Comment: In line 1, the quotes around "String" look a bit wrong. You don't want f to return a literal String "String", do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the syntax in the last line, it's just placeholder syntax for an anonymous function:

```
function1(_.functionDefinedInDog)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
function1(dog => dog.functionDefinedInDog)
```

The concept itself is just passing a function to a function (Higher-order functions). Keep in mind that you're not passing the function defined in dog. You're creating a new anonymous function that will take *any* dog and call a method on it. How `function1` uses that is up to that depends on the definition of `function1`: it might use it several times, or it might not use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is referred to as function application, or applying the value/object to the function.  In your example you are “applying doggy to function f” which can actually be more explicitly written using the word apply.

```
f(doggy) == f.apply(doggy)
```